# How to debug "fatal error with nil while unwrapping an optional value"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, null, forced-unwrapping

This is my first real app I'm writing and I don't understand why I get this "nil" error while unwrapping an optional.

Before I post the code, here's the idea of a simple expense calculator.

I have two textfields (expenseLabel and guestLabel). At the start of the App both should be empty. Here's the first problem. If the user accidentally presses the calculate button I get the following error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

(It's the first line of code I marked down below within ** ... **).

As long as the user enters numbers or the label is not empty at the start of the app (eg. I enter a number in the storyboard) this doesn't happen, but for some strange reason I get the same nil error on the second to last line (again marked within ** ... ** ) when I update the resultLabel.text. Xcode marks this line with the following extra info:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXE_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Here's the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var expenseLabel: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var guestLabel: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func splitButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let expense = expenseLabel.text
    let guests = guestLabel.text

    **var result = Double(expense!)! / Double(guests!)!**
    result = round(result * 100) / 100

    **resultLabel.text = String(result)**
    self.view.endEditing(true)
} 
...
```

It's actually not much code, but I don't understand why I get this error. I even tried the following and introduced the two variables expense and guests before everything else:

```
expense = Double(expenseLabel.text!) ?? 0.0
guests = Double(guestLabel.text!) ?? 0.0
```

I thought this would help to remove the nil unwrapping error, but this didn't work as well.

I feel pretty helpless right now, because again this is not much code and it is for some reason I don't see not working at all.

Comment: My advice to someone learning Swift would be to NEVER force unwrap (aka use a `!` after a variable name) until after you're comfortable with the language. Force unwrapping a value is a very obvious sign you're hacking something & not doing it correctly. Use an `if let` or `guard` to extract that value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check

- Is the `text` property `nil`?
- ( Is the `text` property empty? )
- Can the string in the `text` property be converted to a `Double`?

Strictly spoken in this case the second check can be omitted because an empty string can not be converted to `Double` anyway.

```
if let expense = expenseLabel.text, // !expense.isEmpty, 
   let expenseValue = Double(expense),
   let guests = guestLabel.text, // !guests.isEmpty, 
   let guestValue = Double(guests) {

   let result = round((expenseValue / guestValue) * 100) / 100
   resultLabel.text = String(result)
} else {
   resultLabel.text = "Something went wrong"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!

Comment: Could you please explain in maybe one sentence how the if let statement works? I try to understand that and am trying to create my own, but for some reason mine never worked like yours did now.

Comment: `if let` assigns an unwrapped value of right expression to the following variable otherwise skips the code in the associated `{...}`, this is very very basic Swift stuff.

Comment: Thanks again for your code and explanation. One question though: when the number is for example 276,73 (expenseLabel) the "else" part of the if statement is used and I don't understand why. So instead of doing a calculation it just outputs "Something went wrong"!?

Comment: The default decimal separator is a dot rather than a comma. If you want to consider comma use a number formatter.

Comment: I understand what you mean (thanks again), but when I use the decimal pad as the input keyboard one cannot use a comma (the keyboard provides only a point plus numbers), but still the error exists and I don't see after reading through the apple nsformatter documentation how this would help me!?

Comment: A string containing only digits and a dot is always convertible to `Double`. Consider that the result is only displayed if **all** four expressions evaluate to true.

Comment: Seriously I don't get what I have to do. I don't want the code from you because I like to find this out on my own and I'm now pretty sure it is because of localisation. I used your tip with NSformatter to display a localised currency symbol in the result label and I just realised that on my iPhone the app uses a comma (and obviously a € sign) and on the simulator (where everything works fine a point and a $ sign). So how can I convert or make sure that the local decimal place separator is always a point instead of a comma for instance, because I guess this triggers the else statement.